# If logged username will see different view

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication, navigation, case

I need to make different users'view.

information_view.php
Here's my code:

```
<?
$action = $this->uri->segment(1);
switch ($action) {
  case "home": $this->load->view("homepage_view");break;
 case "users": $this->load->view("users_view"); break;
 case "register": $this->load->view("register_view"); break;
 case "varle": $this->load->view("varle_view"); break;
case "pigu": $this->load->view("pigu_view"); break;
case "search": $this->load->view("search_view"); break;
 case "login": 
  $action2 = $this->uri->segment(2);
  if ($action2 == "success") { $this->load->view("login_success_view"); }
  if ($action2 == "error") { $this->load->view("login_error_view"); }
  break;
  case "profile": $this->load->view("profile_view"); break;
default: $this->load->view("homepage_view"); break;
}
?>
```

navigation_view.php code:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="<?=base_url();?>homepage">Pradinis puslapis</a></li>
<li><a href="<?=base_url();?>register">Registracija</a></li>
<li><a href="<?=base_url();?>search">Paieska</a></li>z
<li><a href="<?=base_url();?>varle">Varle</a></li>
<li><a href="<?=base_url();?>pigu">Pigu</a></li>
</ul>
```

then user logged he must see ("varle_view") and ("pigu_view"); break;
then user log out he must not see varle_view and pigu_view

One more question.

Now it is:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="<?=base_url();?>homepage">Pradinis puslapis</a></li>
<li><a href="<?=base_url();?>register">Registracija</a></li>
<li><a href="<?=base_url();?>search">Paieska</a></li>
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['username'] ) && $_SESSION['username'] == 'mangirdas' ) { ?>
<li><a href="<?=base_url();?>varle">Varle</a></li>
<li><a href="<?=base_url();?>pigu">Pigu</a></li>
<?php  } ?>
</ul>
```

I want that than you are logged that you will not see "register"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't show your login code, but there is no doubt some session vars created on successful login so test for those:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="<?=base_url();?>homepage">Pradinis puslapis</a></li>
<li><a href="<?=base_url();?>register">Registracija</a></li>
<li><a href="<?=base_url();?>search">Paieska</a></li>z
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['UserName'])) { ?>
    <li><a href="<?=base_url();?>varle">Varle</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?=base_url();?>pigu">Pigu</a></li>
<?php  } ?>
</ul>
```

Note that i'm testing for `$_SESSION['UserName']`, you might need to alter that to your session var.